# Depth-first search how it decides to visit node

Tags: search, graph, tree, depth-first-search, depth

Imagine we have a graph like this:

[image]

The DFS would search it in the order of the digits in the picture.

I wonder how it knows when to pick 6 over 8.

I know it searches for the deepest part first but how does it know whether to go for 6 or 8 when the algorithm doesn't know what lies beyond nodes 6 and 8

Comment: It doesn't search the deepest part first. (It's only coincidence that the paths on the left are deepest.) "Depth-first" means means it search down before searching across. "Breadth-first" is the opposite in that it searches across before it searches down.

Comment: The animation at the top of [this page](https://stephanosterburg.gitbook.io/scrapbook/math/algorithm-khan-academy/breadth-first-vs-depth-first-tree-traversal-in-javascript) better illustrates the traversal order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to whether to go for 6 or 8 is simply based on the implementation of the your DFS and the structure of your graph. But no matter it goes to node 6 first or node 8 first, both are the correct implementation of DFS.

let's take a look at this DFS Pseudocode (recursive implementation) as an example:

```
DFS(G, u)
u.visited = true
for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]
    if v.visited == false
        DFS(G,v)
```

so which line of code decides the next adjacent node to go first(pick node 6 or node 8 in your case)? It is the 3rd line

```
 for each v ∈ G.Adj[u]
```

and we know that the "for loop" could have different sequences of iterating the adjacent nodes. someone could also implement it as

```
for(int i=0; i<G.Adj[u].length; i++)
```

or

```
for(int i=G.Adj[u].length-1; i>=0; i--)
```

And these two "for loop" are totally different sequences of picking the next adjacent node.
And also the arraylist of G.Adj[u] could be different from case to case (based on how your initialize the graph).
if the "for loop" gets the node 6 first, it keeps searching down the node 6, otherwise it searches the node 8.
Once again, no matter it picks 6 or 8, both are correct implementation of DFS.